# Calculate the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\log(x)} \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus

Calculate the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\log(x)} \mathrm dx$$ using $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^t-1}{\log(x)} \mathrm dx$$.

Comment: If $$I(t) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{t} - 1}{\log(x)} dx$$ then $I'(t) = \dots$ which can then be integrated to find $I(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mattos hint:

$$I(t) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{t} - 1}{\log(x)} dx$$

Then the derivative with respect to $t$ is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}I(t)= \int_0^1 \frac{x^t\log x }{\log(x)} dx = \int_0^1x^t dx  ... = \frac1{1+t}$$
Hope I did not made a mistake there.
The inital value
$$I(0) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{0} - 1}{\log(x)} dx=0$$

Then you can integrate to get $I(1)$ which is the requested integral:

$$I(1)=I(0)+ \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}I(t) dt= \int_0^1\frac1{1+t}dt=\log 2$$

Comment: I think that integral shuld be ${1 \over {t+1}}$.

Comment: @SayantanSantra. Thanks! I corrected it.